# how to update the file in windows fileshare from the local machine using login credentials in java?

Tags: java, metadata, jcifs

can anybody explain to me, how to proceed in the following scenario ?

i need to update the metadata(like :tag,title) of a file(like: docx,pptx etc) in windows fileshare from the local machine using login credentials  in java .

note :
1.i have  updated the metadata of files which is in local file system using Apache poi .

2.to access a file in the windows share i used jCIFS and i passed the smbFile object reference  as a InputStream  to POIFSFileSystem i am getting a error as below

java.io.IOException: Unable to read entire header; 0 bytes read; expected 512 bytes

this is the code i have tried :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {    

    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain","username","passw0rd$");

        SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile("smb://host/SharedFiles/adoc.doc", auth);

        sFile.connect();

        /* Open the POI filesystem. */
        InputStream is = new SmbFileInputStream(sFile);

        POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
        // is.close();


        /* Read the summary information. */
        DirectoryEntry dir = poifs.getRoot();
        SummaryInformation si;
        try
        {
            DocumentEntry siEntry = (DocumentEntry)
            dir.getEntry(SummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
            DocumentInputStream dis = new DocumentInputStream(siEntry);
            PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(dis);
            dis.close();
            si = new SummaryInformation(ps);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            /* There is no summary information yet. We have to create a new
             * one. */
            si = PropertySetFactory.newSummaryInformation();
        }

        si.setKeywords("mykeyword");

        //   some code ..................



        /* Write the summary information and the document summary information
         * to the POI filesystem. */
        si.write(dir, SummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
        dsi.write(dir, DocumentSummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(poiFilesystem);
        poifs.writeFilesystem(out);
        out.close();

        }
```

the same code works if i try to update the file in local machine but its not working if i try to update in host machine .

plz suggest me is there any other way to do this ? 
thanks in advance .............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write to the fileshare use Jcifs.Try the following code

**Sample:**

```
SmbFile destFile = new SmbFile("smb://host/SharedFiles/adoc.doc", auth);
SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(destFile);
poifs.writeFilesystem(sfos);
sfos.close();
```